# Display current user's (number of) wishlist items in top links, on shared wishlist link

Tags: magento, magento-1.8

When a wishlist having some items, is shared with someone by email, and the invited user visits the link (assuming user is logged in already), the top wishlist link then shows then number of items in wishlist for that shared link rather then it should still show the current user's wishlist (number of) items.

**E.g.**

1. If I have my own wishlist maintained with 4 number of items.
2. Then one of my friend share with me link to see his wishlist with 12 number of items.
3. When I visit that link shared while I am logged in, I see in the number of items shown in wishlist toplink equals to 12
4. Whereas, it should still show 4 items in top wishlist link, as I am still logged in and I do have my own wishlist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it myself after a lot of headbang :) Am posting the solution so another poor soul like me can take a breath.

1. Copy The file `app/code/core/Mage/Wishlist/Helper/Data.php`
2. Look for the function `public function getItemCount() // around line 168 for me`
3. Replace this line `return $this->_getCustomerSession()->getWishlistItemCount();`

With the code below:

```
if(Mage::registry('shared_wishlist') && $this->_isCustomerLogIn()){
            $customer = $this->getCustomer();
            $wishlist = Mage::getModel('wishlist/wishlist')->loadByCustomer($customer, true);
            $wishListItemCollection = $wishlist->getItemCollection();
            return count($wishListItemCollection);
        }
        else{
            return $this->_getCustomerSession()->getWishlistItemCount();
        }
        //return $this->_getCustomerSession()->getWishlistItemCount();
```

And now you will always see current customer wishlist items in toplinks (wishlist link in header), no matter what.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem, but fixed by changing the option Display Wishlist Summary to Display Item quantities.

[image]